# Create instance of model form with data

Tags: django, forms, view, request

This is my code:

```
class asignaForm_web(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model=asignacion
        fields=['usuario']

class asignaForm_view(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model=asignacion
        fields=['usuario','rol','proyecto']

def asignarRol(request,rolid,proyectoid):
    proyectox=proyecto.objects.get(proyecto_id=proyectoid)
    if request.method=='POST':
        #necesito obtener el usuario
        form=asignaForm_web(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usuario=form.cleaned_data['usuario']#aca nose si obtener el user o si con esto es suficiente
            #tengo que crear una asignacion con los datos que ya tengo
            """ asignacionx=asignacion(usuario,rolid,proyectoid)
            #no creo que esto funcione
            asignacionx.save()"""
            formx=asignaForm_view(usuario,rolid,proyectoid)
            formx.save()

            #Volver a la vista de scrum redirigiendo al mismo template con las mismas variables

            return render(request,'rol-flujo-para-scrum.html',{'roles':rol.objects.all(), 'flujos':Flujo.objects.all(),'proyecto':proyectox})

    else:
        form= asignaForm_web()
        return render_to_response('asignaRolProyecto.html',{'formulario':form,'proyecto':proyectox},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It's all in views.py file, when I get a `'GET'` request I send a `form(asignaFOrm_web)` with 1 field and in `'POST'` y pretend to use that one field as a value for data in another `form(asignaForm_view)` which I want to save into the database

I'm not sure about the line

```
formx=asignaForm_view(usuario,rolid,proyectoid)
```

Of it course doesn't work, what is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify names since the form is taking kwargs for fields.

```
kwargs = {
    'proyecto': proyecto.objects.get(proyecto_id=proyectoid),
    'usario': usuario=form.cleaned_data['usuario'],
    'rolid': rolid        
}
AsignaForm(**kwargs) # you should fix the form name to fit camel case,
```

or

```
AsignaForm(proyecto=proyecto.objects.get(proyecto_id=proyectoid),
           usario=usuario=form.cleaned_data['usuario'],
           rolid=rolid)
```